# How can I prove that this map is 1-1 and onto?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions, cyclic-groups

If I have the following homomorphism $f: \mathbb Z_{p^a} \rightarrow \Bbb Z_{p^b}$ defined by multiplication by $n/d$ where $n = p^b$ and $d = \gcd(p^a, p^b).$

How can I prove the following:

1. if $a\geq b$ then $f$ is onto.
2. if $a \leq b$ then $f$ is 1-1.

**My intuition is that I will use the fact that I have cyclic groups but how can I relate that to the relation between $a$ and $b,$ could anyone give me a hint please?**

Comment: Well, the first thing to do is write out what your $n/d$ is more explicitly. If $a \geq b$ then $p^b$ divides $p^a$, so $gcd(p^a,p^b)=p^b$. Then $n/d=1$.

Comment: ok and then what? @leibnewtz , how can that help me to prove that it is onto?

Comment: Well in that case, the map $f$ is just the quotient map. Note this map is well defined since the ideal $(p^a)$ is contained in $(p^b)$. Maybe it helps to write out what $f$ is explicitly; $f(m \, mod p^a)=\frac{n}{d}m \, mod p^b$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on my comment, I'll do $a)$ and leave $b)$ for you to do. The map
$$f: \mathbb{Z}/p^a \mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p^b \mathbb{Z}$$
is given explicitly by $f(x)=\frac{n}{d}x$. In the first case, this simply sends a number mod $p^a$ to itself mod $p^b$. To see that this is surjective, note that the quotient map $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/p^b \mathbb{Z}$ factors through $f$ since $a \geq b$.

To do $b)$, you should first ask yourself why $f$ is well-defined. In other words, if $n=m+kp^a$, then why do we have $f(n)=f(m)$? Then try to show that $f(n)=f(m)$ implies $n=m$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p^a \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: what do you mean in your forth line by "the quotient map $\mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z/p^b \mathbb Z$ **factors through** $f$"?

Comment: Is your $m$ and $n$ that you used in part $(b)$ for explaining to me how to prove  that it is well defined is the same as the $n$ and $m$ I used in my question?

Comment: why should not I prove well definedness in the onto case also?

Comment: In the first part: Do you mean that we have the canonical homomorphism which can be easily proved that it is surjective?

Comment: @Confusion It is strange to see that you accepted an answer about which you have so many questions. You should only accept an answer if you fully understand it. Further, accepting greatly reduces the chance that others may contribute further answers (many users skip questions with accepted answers) - answers which may be more comprehensible at your level, or may provide other viewpoints. Generally you will learn much more if you don't rush acceptance (wait at least a couple days so most active users have a chance to see your question).

Comment: Ok I just accepted it because it **really** clarified many points for me ..... so I am just showing gratitude and respect to the author who takes from his time to answer me. @BillDubuque

Comment: @Confusion That's what upvotes are for. That's not what acceptance is for.

Comment: @BillDubuque ok thanks for clarification :) I promise I will follow that in all my next posts.

Comment: For part $(b),$ here is my problem:                                                                              $f(x)=f(y) \Rightarrow  x p^{b-a} = y p^{b-a} $ but then how can I show that $p^{b-a} < p^a$?

Comment: @Confusion Maybe it's easier to show $f(x)=0$ implies $x=0$. In other words, suppose $p^{b-a}x$ is divisible by $p^b$. What can you say about $x$?

Comment: I am done now with the 1-1 part @leibnewtz thank you!